How can I get static values from a Type parameter in Java?
I'm trying to write the framework for a robot path planner, and I have an abstract class called Plan which contains some Movements and a MovementType enum value:
public abstract class Plan<T extends RobotState> { 

    protected MovementType movementType;
    ...

    /**
     * Creates a new Plan object with the given Movements.
     * @param movements
     */
    public Plan(Movement... movements) {
        this.movementType = ... // I need to get the MovementType from T
        this.movements = movements;
    }
    ...

}

where the RobotState  class is extended by TranslationState  and RotationState . I'm looking to store a MovementType  enum value in these subclasses in a way that I can get it directly from T  in the first line of the constructor (line 9). This is an ExamplePlan class that inherits from Plan<TranslationState>:
public class ExamplePlan extends Plan<TranslationState> {

    // when this gets constructed, movementType should equal MovementType.TRANSLATION

}

I know that abstract static MovementType getMovementType()  can't be declared in RobotState  because it's static, and I don't really want to pass a MovementType  through the Plan constructor parameters because it feels redundant; there are plenty of other generic classes in the framework that depend on the MovementType of a RobotState and I don't wan't MovementTypes cluttering all the code.
Is there a standard way I should be doing this, or is this not possible and do I have to use a workaround? Thanks.

I would go with the constructor parameter as the clearest solution, and look for ways to remove the need for a type parameter to eliminate the redundancy.

You can use some reflection magic to capture the type of T from the subclass, and then use that to map to your enum:
abstract class Plan<T extends RobotState> {
    protected final MovementType movementType;

    Plan() {
        var genericType = (ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        var actualType = (Class<T>)genericType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        movementType = MovementType.forState(actualType);
    }
}

enum MovementType {
    TRANSLATION(TranslationState.class),
    ROTATION(RotationState.class);

    public static MovementType forState(Class<? extends RobotState> state) {
        for (var type : values()) {
            if (type.state == state) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final Class<? extends RobotState> state;

    MovementType(Class<? extends RobotState> state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

But beware that it's hacky and brittle. For example, it won't work if you instantiate Plan directly. An alternative is to pass the type object into the constructor, but then you're not gaining much except reducing the risk of mismatching the enum on construction.
